# Ruby Environment Variables?

Tags: ruby, windows, environment-variables

I'm looking into learning some Ruby, I've installed it on Windows 7 X64 using the installer you can find at [RubyInstaller.org](http://www.rubyinstaller.org) .

Now my problem is that the installation is done and all that. But when I try and check for the ruby version in command prompt e.g

```
ruby -v
```

I just get an error saying that my system doesn't know what that is. Including ruby -e and ruby -s etc... Now coming from a Java background I assume that this has something to do with environment variables that might not be set for Ruby?

How exactly does one go about this to quickly get set up?

Comment: Just download and install works..check the list of applications and start irb from there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to edit your `PATH` variable. My `PATH` variable contain `C:\Ruby192\bin`, in this folder there are files `ruby` and `irb`.

Also I think there is an option for that in the installator, which you may check.

Comment: It's so weird, I actually did check the box that adds the path to my PATH and when I went and checked it it was indeed there. I went and added this not to Path and CLASSPATH. Yet still nothing.

Comment: That is pretty much what I'm getting also yes. C:\Ruby193\bin is there. Am I doing something wrong maybe running "ruby -v"? You run this in the normal straight windows command prompt right? - I'll try re-installing

Comment: @Speranksy Danil - I did an re-install and everything is working now! Thanks for your help, made clear that everything was fine so something must've gone wrong in my installation. Anyway, it's working. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, make sure you do not have TWO ruby installations in your path.  My problem was that I did not have bundler installed for the ruby version that I was trying to use (Ruby 2.1) but it found and was using bundler for Ruby 1.9.3.  Removing ruby 1.9.3 from `PATH` and running `gem install bundler` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find Ruby installation path. Maybe something like "C:\Ruby193...". There is a bin dir under that.
2. Add the bin dir to your PATH env.

Answer (score 0):

The advice to check the PATH option on install is good.

Another thing that helped me was searching Windows for "Start Command Prompt with Ruby." From that command line, Ruby worked well and I am able to watch my XAMPP directory for SASS changes. I was never able to get that to work using either Git Bash or the regular Windows command line, but the Command Prompt with Ruby worked like a charm.